# mysql compare 2 dates

Tags: java, mysql, sql, date, datetime

I'm absolute noob in Java and Mysql. Have an assignment to make where user need to login and register. All code been done. But there is one little part where the user's login should expire in 6 month. I'm trying to accomplish it by using `SELECT DATEDIFF(month,'2014-06-05','2014-08-05') AS DiffDate`. I can track user's registry date but with the second date I'm a bit stumped. How can I track the current time of user login. Any suggestions. Thank you.

Comment: So you want current date as second date? Like `NOW()` or `CURDATE()`?

Comment: You certainly can but why do the comparison with SQL at all? When you load user/session data from db to check session state you can as well compare current time with the time from db in java. You also will have to store session data in your db (or in a cache layer or even just in local memory) for that to work. Like `UPDATE users SET last_login=NOW() WHERE userid = ?`

Comment: yes that's what i'm trying to achieve. But my output saying:  "Incorrect parameter count in the call to native function 'DATEDIFF'" if I'm using SELECT DATEDIFF(month,'dayLastLogin',NOW()) AS DiffDate FROM user'. Querying with JAVA in NETBEANS

Answer (score 1):

You can use MySQL [NOW()](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_now.asp) :

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(month,'2014-06-05',NOW()) AS DiffDate
```

Comment: My output saying: "Incorrect parameter count in the call to native function 'DATEDIFF'" if I'm using 'SELECT DATEDIFF(month,'dayLastLogin',NOW()) AS DiffDate FROM user'. Querying with JAVA in NETBEANS